# File upload into directory doesnt work, there are no files

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

```
public function imgUploader()
 {
     $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     $targetDir = "guestebuch/images";


     if ( !empty($filename) && move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $targetDir.$filename) )
     {
         echo "Successfully uploaded.";
         echo "<br>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "Error.";
         echo "<br>";
     }
 }
```

When I run the code it works but there are no files / images in the directory.

Comment: Check permissions in your folder.

Comment: `$targetDir = "guestebuch/images/";` See the last slash? Now try to understand why this slash is __required__.

Comment: The path for the target file is incorrect - should be `$targetDir.'/'.$filename` perhaps

Comment: Target Directory in move uploaded file is incorrect it'll give you "guestebuch/images".filename, Please add $targetDir.'/'.$filename;

Answer (score -1):

Just change this line

```
if ( !empty($filename) && move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $targetDir.$filename))
```

to

```
if ( !empty($filename) && move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $targetDir.'/'.$filename) )
```